# How to use “Native Wifi API” Windows API functions with ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, winapi, wifi, wlanapi

My Setup: Windows 7, Ruby 1.9.3

I want to manage the wireless NIC to access different Wireless Routers, here's what I have tried:

### Method 1: `netsh  wlan`

Managing the WLAN adapter through the `netsh` command tools.

So I setup my Wireless Network in Windows and exported it using

```
netsh wlan export profile name="wuhongliang" folder = "d:\" interface="Wireless" key=clear
```

Which worked, I can then add the profile and connect by doing:

```
> netsh wlan add profile ^
filename="d:\wireless-wuhongliang.xml" ^
interface="wireless" Profile

wuhongliang is added on interface Wireless.

> netsh wlan connect name="wuhongliang" ^
ssid="wuhongliang"
Connection request was completed successfully.
```

Which works and connects me to the WLAN using the exported profile.

So looking at the XML Profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
  <name>wuhongliang</name>
  <SSIDConfig>
    <SSID>
      <hex>7775686F6E676C69616E67</hex>
      <name>wuhongliang</name>
    </SSID>
  </SSIDConfig>
  <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
  <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
  <MSM>
    <security>
      <authEncryption>
        <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
        <encryption>AES</encryption>
        <useOneX>false</useOneX>
      </authEncryption>
      <sharedKey>
        <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
        <protected>true</protected>
        <keyMaterial>[Long Encrypted Key]</keyMaterial>
      </sharedKey>
    </security>
  </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

The `keyMaterial` is obviously the encrypted network password. So if I change the router password then the profile breaks because I don't have the new encrypted `keyMaterial`.

Since I don't know how to generate the `keyMaterial` this won't work for me.

### Method 2: using `wlanapi.dll`

I found [this article on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72105/Manage-WiFi-with-Native-API-WIFI-on-Windows-XP-SP2) and it looked promising. But I have no experience in C#,C,C++.

I tried using the `dll` with `Ruby DL` and `Win32API` but I don't how to set the parameters or use those libraries in general.

This is the Ruby code I used call the `WlanEnumInterfaces` API (but I'm pretty sure it's incorrect):

```
c_handle = 1
c_reserved = 0
c_interfacelist=" "*10000 
dllname = "wlanapi.dll" 
pro=Win32API.new(dllname, "WlanEnumInterfaces", ['p', 'l', 'p'], "v") 
p pro.call(handle, c_reserved, c_interfacelist) 
p c_interfacelist.unpack("l*")
```

Comment: Please edit the question so that it is readable. You don't have Javascript that we can run.

Comment: I am sorry about the format of the question,I have spent about 3 hours  to edit the text of the question,It's difficult to me to do this, but I'll modify it slowly,please don't delete my question, TKS

Comment: Thank you very much for editing the question for me,although I don't who you are

Answer (score 1):

In the `sharedKey` tag change the `protected` value to `false` and the `keyMaterial` value can be imported in `plaintext`.

```
<sharedKey>
    <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <keyMaterial>[The Password]</keyMaterial>
  </sharedKey>
```

The `key=clear` option was *supposed* to do that for you, but it obviously wasn't.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer !  It works<br>
I really want to learn how to invoke the `wlanapi.dll` with ruby<br>
I will have to invoke some other win32api like `user32`,`kernel32`,so,if I master how to use the `wlanapi`,I'll know how to do these.  Could you please help me?

Comment: That's another question entirely. One that has to deal with how to use `dll`s from Ruby.